# Проверка даты в Entity Fraemwork 6, аннотация даты, времени

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datetime, аннотации, entity

Есть автосвойство с датой:

```
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime date { get; set; }
```

Как правильно сделать проверку на минимальную или максимальную дату, например:

01.01.2020 < DateTime.Now

для типов int, double есть [Range(min,max)], а для типов DateTime, TimeSpan в аннотациях ничего не могу найти, я так понимаю, нужно отдельно создавать свой метод для проверки, если да, то подскажите как сделать более правильно, буду признателен.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: У вас есть же сеттер, сделайте в нем проверку. Но лучше проверку на валидность даты делать на этапе ввода данных.

Comment: Посмотрите здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406046/data-annotation-ranges-of-dates#2907678

Answer (score 3):

Спасибо большое за ссылку, то-что нужно:

```
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[Range(typeof(DateTime),"1/1/2020","1/1/2030",ErrorMessage = 
  "Value for {0} must be between {1} and {2}")]
public DateTime date { get; set; }
```

Решение идеальное!